# Pandas data frame merge unique values

Tags: python, pandas, merge, finance

I have two dataframes(df3 & dfA) - one with unique values only(df3), the other with multiple values(dfA).

I want to add a column 'Trdr' from dfA to DF3 based on column 'ISIN'

The issue is : dfA has multiple lines with the same ISIN with a 'Trdr' value. Therefore when I try to merge the datasets it adds a row line for every ISIN that has a 'trdr' value.

In laymans terms, I want to Vlookup the 1st value that pandas can find in dfA and assign it to df3.

```
'''df3=pd.merge( df3,dfA[['Trdr','ISIN']],how="left",on='ISIN')'''
```

[df3 before the merge showing unique ISINs only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLnY.png)
[dfA showing the trdr values im trying to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmqeJ.png)
[df3 after the merge showing multiple lines of VODAFONE rather than 1 unique value as per initial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0km6b.png)

Comment: please share minimal reproducible example

Comment: Can you drop duplicates using the ISIN subset on dfA prior to merging?

Comment: you can drop the duplicates using the values of df3, using [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates)